# Fetching sorted set has escape characters in Redis

Tags: java, redis

I am trying to fetch an entire sorted set from redis.

I can see the proper string in Redis Insight:
[image]

But when I try to fetch using any library such as redisson, lettuce, redis-cli etc., it returns a string with escape characters added.

How can I prevent this / mitigate this issue with less CPU overhead? I can try to parse the result in the app itself and then return a formatted string. But that would take processing and latency is important for me here.

[image]